# Canculate difference between two date and times

Tags: datetime, excel-formula

I'm using IFTTT to tell me when a light is turned on and off. It gives me a record such as "August 13, 2014 at 06:05PM" in one column and "August 13, 2014 at 07:10PM" is there a way to calculate the number of minutes between the two entries?

Comment: try google before SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would work on it like this, I will start with one of your dates as an example:

I pasted the date in cell B3
B3= August 13, 2014 at 06:05PM

1. Get rid of the word "at"
   -excel formula =FIND("at",B3)
   -I added this result to C3
2. Replace the "at" with an empty string ("")
   -excel formula =REPLACE(B3, C3, 3, "")
   -I added this result to D3
3. Insert a space between the time and the AM/PM modifier
   -excel formula =CONCATENATE(LEFT(D3, (LEN(D3)-2))," ", RIGHT(D3, 2))
   -I added this result to E3
4. Now you have a valid date, and you can subtract, giving you the result in days
5. Convert days to minutes by multiplying by 1440 (24 hours in day * 60 minutes per hour)

Hope that helps.